# Library to convert PDF table to CSV/Dataframe from Appengine python 3 app

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, pdf

I have an appengine python3 app that needs to convert some tables in a PDF file to some readable format (csv or dataframe would work).  Locally I was using tabula-py, but that does not run on the appengine python3 environment because it relies on Java which the python3 runtime of course doesn't provide.  I'm having trouble finding other libraries that do what tabula does, but will work on python3 appengine app.

I could write a small appengine java app which simply converts the pdf using tabula, and then sends that off to my python3 app, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [GAE Flex Custom runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart) would work here:

> Custom runtimes let you build apps that run in an environment defined by a Dockerfile. By using a Dockerfile, you can use languages and packages that are not part of the Google Cloud Platform and use the same resources and tooling that are used in the App Engine flexible environment.

If you can define your own [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) and make your code work using the library that you need, then you can deploy it to App Engine

Comment: This is what I've started doing, the migration hasn't been that bad and definitely gives us more flexibility.